# Why does this entity result in so many index writes?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following entity (specified via JDO):

```java
    @PersistenceCapable(
        identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
    public class Subscription {
      @PrimaryKey
      @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;

      @Persistent
      private String user;

      @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
      private Link feedUrl;

      @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
      @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.unindexed", value="true")
      private Link hubUrl;

      @Persistent
      @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.unindexed", value="true")
      private String title;

      @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
      @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.unindexed", value="true")
      private Set<String> seenEntryIds;
    }
```

(see full entity definition [here](http://code.google.com/p/push-bot/source/browse/src/info/persistent/pushbot/data/Subscription.java))

It has only three indexed properties, `id`, `user` and `feedUrl`. When running on the dev server, the console says that each entity results in 6 write ops.

However, when running in production, the quota details page says that there have been 4,276 entity put ops, and 164,110 index write ops, which gives an average of 38 index writes per entity. That's much higher than I would expect, and also much higher than what the dev server shows.

I added the `gae.unindexed` property [late yesterday](http://code.google.com/p/push-bot/source/detail?spec=svnf763dfe2c572eba2120af43f506989414c316d8e&r=dec3233e544584424d74bfcc755837ebff21fe32), and pushed the change then too. I would therefore expect all of the entity puts that happen today (which is what the quota details page reports) to not reflect any of the extra index writes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess was that had an old `WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml` laying about, but you don't appear to have one (and it isn't in your `.gitignore`).

What's the mean size of the `seenEntryIds` set? If it's ~16, that gives me an idea for a test case.

Comment: Indeed there are no custom indices. The mean size of `seenEntryIds` is 324 (most feeds update pretty often, and the maximum number kept is 1000).

Comment: Also, now that the quota cycle has begun again, the current ratio is 8.5 index writes per put (2,088 index writes, 245 puts). That's still higher than expected, but lower than before.

Comment: As a final detail, most (~50%) of the puts in this cycle have been for the same entity (a feed that updates constantly), which has long ago reached the upper bound of 1,000 `seenEntryIds.`

Comment: Weird. Given how you've set things up, I'd expect 6 writes for a new Subscription.

Comment: It appears to be trending in that direction. The most recent ratio for today is 6.6 index writes per put (22,108 index writes, 3351 puts).

Comment: This appears to have fixed itself, so for lack of anything better I'm going to accept your answer. Thanks for investigating!